# WatiN error ElementNotFoundException

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, watin

When I am attempting to run the unit tests against my website, I suddenly started receiving the following error:

```
WatiN.Core.Exceptions.ElementNotFoundException was unhandled by user code
  Message=Could not find A element tag matching criteria: Attribute 'href' equals uri     'https://my.companyurl.com/client/clientupload.aspx' at     https://my.companyurl.com/account/default.aspx
  Source=WatiN.Core
  StackTrace:
       at WatiN.Core.Element.get_NativeElement()
       at WatiN.Core.Element.GetAttributeValueImpl(String attributeName)
       at WatiN.Core.Component.GetAttributeValue(String attributeName)
       at WatiN.Core.Element.get_Enabled()
       at WatiN.Core.Element.ClickImpl(Boolean waitforComplete)
       at WatiN.Core.Element.Click()
       at UnitTests.MyUploadFileClass.ClickNavigateToUploadFile() in     D:\DevProjects\MyWebApp\test\UnitTests\Tests\MyUploadFileClass.cs:line 40
       at UnitTests.MyUploadFileClassTest.UploadNewFileTest() in     D:\DevProjects\MyWebApp\test\UnitTests\Tests\MyUploadFileClassTest.cs:line 110
  InnerException:
```

Also receiving exceptions like this:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException was unhandled by user code
  Message=The interface is unknown. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706B5)
  Source=Interop.SHDocVw
  ErrorCode=-2147023179
  StackTrace:
       at SHDocVw.InternetExplorerClass.set_Visible(Boolean pBool)
       at WatiN.Core.Native.InternetExplorer.IEBrowser.set_Visible(Boolean value)
       at WatiN.Core.IE.FinishInitialization(Uri uri)
       at WatiN.Core.IE.CreateNewIEAndGoToUri(Uri uri, IDialogHandler logonDialogHandler, Boolean createInNewProcess)
       at WatiN.Core.IE..ctor(String url)
```

The tests used to pass previously with no problem, so I'm not sure why this error started occuring.  Does anyone have any suggestions?  TIA.

Comment: paste the page HTML here, it sounds like you don't have an anchor tag with the URI you are looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually resolved the problems by performing three steps: 1) Updated the URLs because my coworker had changed them. 2) Ran Visual Studio as administrator. 3) In IE9 went to Tools->Internet Options->Security tab->Local Intranet. Clicked on the sites button and removed the check box from "Automatically detect intranet network". Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

it could be that you are now using a different browser, or a different version. Can you test it in the old browser where it used to work and see if it still works?

Comment: no problem. glad it is working. you should probably post an answer yourself and mark it as complete for future visitors.